# Generating true random numbers

Tags: random, passwords

In my cryptography lessons I learned that one should use as many parameters together as possible in order to have the entropy to generate a close to perfect random number. My question is: Let's say I would just measure the temperature of room at a given moment (e.g. 19,6573°C), would the number not be already random enough? I mean an attacker could not possibly guess my room temperature and he could also not measure it afterwards, because he would need to go back in time.

Since cryptographic algorithms would turn my temperature from 19,6573 to a string of 512 characters or more and an attacker would not be able to reproduce the measurement, my random number should be random enough, shouldn't it?

Comment: An attacker could assume your room temperature is between say 18°C and 25°C which would give a range between 180.000 and 250.000 so 70.000 combinations. Would this be enough for you from a security point of view?

Comment: That's a good point. So the attacker needs to know my generating algorithm to make an attack? But then again that's probably the case in most attacking scenarios.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Try [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Using a single measurement is hardly enough for security purposes.  For example, if a measurement takes a small number of possible values (say, tenths of a degree with a range of 0 to 100000) and you hash that number to a 512-bit block, then the 512-bit block will still have the same small number of possible values.

Comment: You would have do some analysis to be able to estimate how much entropy is in a single measurement and/or a sequence of measurements.